# Issue with manually giving password every time with psql

Tags: bash, postgresql, amazon-rds, psql, aws-aurora-serverless

We are trying to migrate data from one Amazon RDS database to Amazon Aurora Serverless database using `psql` of postgresql by **COPY** command. The script is working fine when I run it from an EC2 instance but I need to give password for **rdswizard** and **postgres** every iteration manually. I just want to give the password along with my `psql` command. How to give password along with the `psql` command not manually every time?

```
allSites=(3 5 9 11 29 30 31 32 33 34 37 38 39 40 41 45 46 47 48)

for i in "${allSites[@]}"
do
   psql \
    -X \
    -U rdswizard \
    -h my_rds_host_url_goes_here \
    -d wizard \
    -c "\\copy (select site_id,name,phone from client_${i} where date(create_date) > '2019-09-11' LIMIT 100) to stdout" \
| \
psql \
    -X \
    -U postgres \
    -h my_aurora_serverless_host_url_goes_here \
    -d wizard \
    -c "\\copy client_${i}(site_id,name,phone) from stdin"
done
```

**Both of my database host is on remote server not in local machine**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add details to `~/.pgpass` file to avoid regularly having to type in passwords. Make sure to provide `-rw-------(0600)` permissions to the file.

> This file should contain lines of the following format:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

The password field from the first line that matches the current connection parameters will be used. Refer [official documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/app-psql.html)

Comment: So for two host I need to use two lines on pgpass file?

Comment: Correct. The corresponding password will automatically be picked on the basis of your connection (hostname, database, username).

Comment: Let me check it out today at office and then I'll let you know

Comment: Your solution works fine, I just did a small change, `PGPASSFILE=~/.pgpass` added before my `psql` command. **See here:** https://newfivefour.com/postgresql-pgpass-password-file.html